# Group files by common substring in their names

Tags: bash

I have a directory with this kind of organization :

```
header1[pattern1].extension
header1[pattern2].extension
header2[pattern1].extension
header2[pattern2].extension
```

So I would like to move the files to new directories which are named after the corresponding patterns:

```
pattern1
    header1[pattern1].extension
    header2[pattern1].extension

pattern2
    header1[pattern2].extension
    header2[pattern2].extension
```

The problem is that I don't know the patterns in advance. I tried a for loop with grep but I'm not familiar with bash commands, so I couldn't manage to save the pattern into a variable and create the new directory accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need grep for that (or awk), strings between brackets can be extracted using parameter expansions. Assuming no *pattern* names an existing file that isn't a directory or a symbolic link to a directory in the current directory, this should do the trick:

```
for f in *\[?*]*; do
  d=${f#*\[} d=${d%]*}
  echo mkdir -p -- "$d"
  echo mv -- "$f" "$d"
done
```

Drop `echo`s if the output looks good.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk to extract the pattern

```
for i in header*.extension;
do 
   patt=$(awk -F '[][]' '{ print $2 }' <<< "$i");     # Set the field delimiter to [ or ] in awk and print the second delimited field ($2), reading the result into the variable patt
   if [[ -d "$patt" ]]                                # If the contents of patt exists as a directory, just move the file, otherwise, create the directory and move the file
   then
      echo "mv $i $patt";
      # mv "$i" "$patt";
   else
      echo "mkdir $patt && mv $i $patt;
      # mkdir "$patt" && mv "$i" "$patt";
   fi
 done
```

Verify the command with echo and then remove the comment flags to execute the actual commands.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#` if the output looks good.

```sh
for i in header*.extension;
do
  if [[ $i =~ (header)([0-9]{1})\[(.*)\](.txt) ]]; then
    match=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    echo "moving $i to $match folder"
    # mkdir -p "$match" && mv $i $match
  else
    echo "$i: Not matched"
  fi
done
```

Structure before code execution:

```
.
├── header1[bad].extension
├── header1[good].extension
├── header2[bad].extension
├── header2[good].extension
└── script.sh
```

Structure after you run `bash script.sh` after un-commenting the 6th line

```
.
├── bad
│   ├── header1[bad].extension
│   └── header2[bad].extension
├── good
│   ├── header1[good].extension
│   └── header2[good].extension
└── script.sh
```